# PHP : echo a href

Tags: php, echo, href

I have this php line which works fine:

```
echo "<p><a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/". $post['id'] . "\"target=\"_blank\">" . $post['message']. "</a></p>";
```

But I want to change it so it will link to my page (not to a single post). So it should look like that.

```
echo "<p><a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/rscmovement" "\"target=\"_blank\">" . $post['message']. "</a></p>";
```

I have tried a lot many proposition gathered on different website, but each time I am getting an error.

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Get rid of your errant parenthesis `$post['message'])` <-- here

Comment: escape the quotes after rscmovement and get rid of the additional one after it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using single and double quotes, you avoid escaping issues. Try this:

```
echo '<p><a href="https://www.facebook.com/rscmovement" target="_blank">'. $post['message']. '</a></p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

i see that you didn't escaped from double quote that closes href attribute:

```
echo "<p><a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/rscmovement\" target=\"_blank\">"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess You have missed the back slash () before " after  www.facebook.com/rscmovement. 
"

https://www.facebook.com/rscmovement\" "\"target=\"_blank\">"  will